# Delete XML node with SimpleXML, PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to delete XML node with PHP (SimpleXML).

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <a>
        <name>A1</name>
        <b>
            <title>Item1</title>
            <url>item1</url>
        </b>
        <b>
            <title>Item2</title>
            <url>item2</url>
        </b>
        <b>
            <title>Item3</title>
            <url>item3</url>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <name>A2</name>
        <b>
            <title>Item1</title>
            <url>item1</url>
        </b>
    </a>
</items>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET["xml"]);
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());


    $ID = $_GET["ID"];
    $i = -1;
    $num = $_GET["num"];

    foreach ($sxe->children() as $var) {
        if ($var == $ID) {
            foreach ($var->children() as $data) {
                if ($data == "link") {
                    $i++;

                    if ($i == $num) {
                        if ( ! empty($sxe)) {
                            unset($sxe[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $sxe->asXML($_GET["xml"]);  
?>
```

This code looks for  with data of $ID (for example, $ID="A1"). The node it looks to delete is a  node (with its  and ), which is the #$num  node.

Example: if $ID="A1" and $num=1,
it needs to delete the  node with the title "Item2" and url "item2".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath to find a node. With your example it will be

```
//a[name="A1"]/b[2]
```

and use `DomDocument` method `removeChild` to change xml

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$node = $sxe->xpath('//a[name="'. $ID .'"]/b['. $num .']');
$dom=dom_import_simplexml($node[0]);
$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Comment: Is the $str the xml file? (file.xml) or should I load it to $str? ($xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET["xml"]);
$str = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());)

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in deletenode.php on line 72

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): links.xml in deletenode.php on line 72

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in deletenode.php on line 72

Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in deletenode.php on line 73

(72 is $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);)

Comment: You can save your code: `$xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET["xml"]);
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());`

Comment: or `$sxe = simplexml_load_file($_GET["xml"]);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! My problem was that the index starts at 1 and not 0, so the solution was with ($num+1).

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention  that path counts from one but not a zero-based